# Why am I getting a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to Import from library.sb_utils?

Tags: python, import, module

When I input the following: `from library.sb_utils import save_file`

I am getting the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: `No module named 'library'`

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

try redownloading it on your computer terminal

eg. on mac it is:

```
pip3 install library
```